# How to get WeakReference in doInBackground() of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, weak-references

I have a class named `RetrieveCoverImageTask`. It retrieves the actual cover image from the URL in a `Track` instance:

```
private class RetrieveCoverImageTask extends AsyncTask<Track, Void, Void> {

    private WeakReference<Context> context;

    RetrieveCoverImageTask(Context context) {
        this.context = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    // V1
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Track... tracks) {
        Context context = this.context.get();
        if (context != null) {
            for (Track track : tracks) {
                try {
                    Bitmap bmp = Picasso.with(context).load(track.getCoverUrl()).get();
                    if (bmp != null) {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        track.setCoverImage(stream.toByteArray());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // V2
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Track... tracks) {
        for (Track track : tracks) {
            try {
                Context context = this.context.get();
                if (context != null) {
                    Bitmap bmp = Picasso.with(context).load(track.getCoverUrl()).get();
                    if (bmp != null) {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        track.setCoverImage(stream.toByteArray());
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

An example call from an `Activity` is as below:

```
new RetrieveCoverImageTask(context).execute(track1, track2, track3);
```

First, I did V1. Then, I thought that the image retrieval with Picasso takes time and the calling `Activity` may become null in the meanwhile, therefore, I have to get context at the beginning of each iteration of the for loop. That's how I implemented V2.

Which version of `doInBackground()` is efficient and error-resistant? V1 or V2?

Comment: I realized that WeakReference's get() method returns strong reference. So, once I get the Context, the Activity will not be garbage collected until doInBackground() finishes. So, V2 may not worth using since it does extra get() calls in each loop compared to V1's one get() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efficiency is probably not the biggest issue here. V2 is safer, but the whole thing is not very "elegant". It would be much easier to set something up with RxJava. You would not need WeakReferences. The key would be to dispose of your subscription when the context becomes invalid (e.g. `onDestroy()`) and you would save the check for null.

Also you might want to use an approach to getting the bmp that does not involve picasso and thus does not require context. Or you use the application context which exists as long as your application is running, so you do not need the null check

Comment: I cannot use RxJava in this project. Other methods can be used to retrieve bitmap, however, I wondered which way is better if a context is involved.

Comment: if you have to take V1 or V2 then V2 is better. Performance will not differ much here.

Answer (score 0):

The WeakReference.get is correct.

If you want to use Picasso, you can do it directly on the View (probably onBindViewholder) cause it already do it in background.

If you want to use a task you need to download the stream instead with a URLConnection to be efficiently, or OkHttp (latest version, cause its embedded as the URLConnection)

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of using Picasso in async task because Picasso anyway loads image asynchronously on a different thread. Also, you are storing bitmaps in variables which will cost you a lot of memory because bitmaps are heavy and all of them will be stored in the ram even when they are not required. A better approach would be to directly use Picasso in your ViewHolder as pointed by Marcos Vasconcelos.

Comment: I am actually using Picasso in ViewHolder for thumbnail image to be used in ListView. Cover image is for another step.

Comment: Judging from your source code, you'll probably show the image when the music track is selected. For that case also ,its better that you should load image when it is required, because it will be cached anyway in future. You can show the thumbnail image there when full image is loading.

Comment: You don't need an async task for this purpose because Picasso anyway loads in a different background thread. You can just call do in background normally.  And you can cancel all your requests in onStop/onDestroy of your activity. No memory leaks will be there in that case.